# When two users access the same method, the result is shared

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, thermal-printer

I came across this issue when 2 different users of my website created a product sale at the same time. This should generate 2 different requests to the server and print 2 different sale tickets. The problem is that when the server requests come in at the same time (or very close from each other), both branches print the same tickets, instead of each printing its own ticket.

Here's my code:

```
Branch          Total   CreatedAt               ProductSaleId
EBQ Centro Maya 35.00   2016-06-13 15:35:54.743 3263825d-bca3-4d18-bbca-3eebe4c3398a
EBQ PA Chetumal 30.00   2016-06-13 15:35:54.647 01f52d7d-5745-426b-a973-4a701a18b8e4
```

These are the DB entries, 2 different branches made a sale each at 15:35:54.

So, once the sale is made, PrintReceipt method is called like this:

```
HelperObjects.ThermalPOS58.PrinterController.PrintReceipt(new InvoiceReceipt()
            {
                Discount = discount,
                InvoiceNumber = "TEST",
                SubTotal = decimal.Parse(createProductSale.Total),
                Total = total,
                Change = createProductSale.Change ?? "0",
                ClientAmount = createProductSale.ClientAmount,
                InvoiceDateFormatted =
                    DateTime.UtcNow.ConvertUtcTimeToTimeZone("", User.Identity.GetUserId())
                        .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                BranchName = _unitOfWork.BranchRepository.GetById(branchId).Name,
                InvoiceItems = invoiceReceipts,
                PrinterName = _unitOfWork.BranchRepository.GetById(branchId).PrinterName,
                IsTpv = createProductSale.IsTpv
            });
```

PrintReceipt method looks like this:

```
private static InvoiceReceipt _mappedInvoice ;

    public static void PrintReceipt(InvoiceReceipt invoiceReceipt)
    {
        _mappedInvoice = invoiceReceipt;
        var printNodeIntegration = new PrintNodeIntegration();
        printNodeIntegration.Print(GetDocument(), invoiceReceipt.PrinterName);
    }
```

Each call is sending its own invoice to the PrintReceipt method and it works fine EXCEPT when the sales are made at the same time. When this happens, both branches are printing the same receipt. Usually the one that came in first.

Any ideas?

Comment: `static` members are shared across all sessions.  Use `Session` or figure out a different way to keep the invoice in state.

Comment: Where else are you using `_mappedInvoice`? Why do you need a static member at all?

Comment: The static looks suspicious, but shouldn't affect this in the code provided, unless it is used in GetDocument() (big red flag here, I suspect); so, what does GetDocument() actually do? show the code for GetDocument().  if GetDocument() uses the static variable _mappedInvoice, then why use a static rather than just pass invoiceReceipt to GetDocument()?

Comment: You need to define a critical section in the PrintReceipt method using Lock or Monitor or some other synchronization primitive.

Comment: @DStanley: I don't, really. Looks like major confusion on my side.

Comment: @MattJordan: It is indeed used in GetDocument(), which is the method that translates the invoice data into ESC/POS code for the printer. I think I'm just going to make the entire call non-static; seems like the correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` members are shared within the *process*.  In ASP.NET all sessions in an app pool use the same process, so they all share the same `static` state.

The static `Session` property separates data by user session, so it is a *better* place to hold session-specific data:

```
Session["mappedInvoice"] = invoiceReceipt;
```

But it's unclear how you're using it to know if it even needs to be stored in the session.  Typically You use the session to hold data that needs to persist across requests.

Comment: You're right, I don't actually need this info stored in the session, since it's just a single request. And, most importantly, sharing the same state sounds like exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. Seems like making it non-static will solve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static InvoiceReceipt _mappedInvoice ;
private readonly static Object _lockObject = new Object();

public static void PrintReceipt(InvoiceReceipt invoiceReceipt)
{
    Lock(_lockObject)
    {
        _mappedInvoice = invoiceReceipt;
        var printNodeIntegration = new PrintNodeIntegration();
        printNodeIntegration.Print(GetDocument(), invoiceReceipt.PrinterName);
    }
}
```

This prevents calls that come in between when _mappedInvoice is set and .Print is called from resetting _mappedInvoice. The later call will wait until the current call releases the lock.

Comment: This is needlessly preventing these operations from running in parallel, when there's no reason for them to not run in parallel.

Comment: There may be a specific reason for going with a static method here (the question was not stated otherwise). If so, this answer explains why his code behaves like it does, and how to fix it. You have no way of knowing from the information stated in the original question that this is not the case. You made an assumption that he does not have need of a static method. I agree that all things equal, parallel execution would be better assuming there is no specific reason for using static.

Comment: The question made it clear that the data in question is in fact request specific, and even *showed* example data for each request.  It's not an assumption that this data shouldn't be shared; it's *a part of the explicit requirements given* that the information not be shared.

Comment: This is a Point Of Sale (POS) system not a web site, it is not a question of sharing the data across calls, it is a question of printing the correct receipt for each call. His printer is printing the same receipt for the two calls that come in too close together. This code will prevent that by serializing the output calls to the printer.

Comment: Now who's making lots of assumptions about the OP's specific situation.  We don't actually know the details of what this is doing to know whether or not access to that method needs to be synchronized.  All that the question is asking about is ensuring each request keeps its data separate.  If the operation he's performing also need to ensure only one request can access a given system resource at a time then that's a separate issue.

Comment: This is indeed a POS but my mistake was needlessly making it a static class. I guess you're both correct since I may have misled Kevin.There's really no specific reason for making this static and I would definitely want the operations running in parallel. As such, I believe my problem will be solved by just making it non-static.